# Flutter generic class casting "type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Object>' in type cast"

Tags: flutter, dart, generics

I have generic api response model which is JsonSerializable. here is the class.

```
  @JsonSerializable()
class ApiResponseBaseModel<T> {
  @JsonKey(fromJson: _dataFromJson, toJson: _dataToJson)
  T innerData;
  bool succeeded;

  ApiResponseBaseModel({this.innerData, this.succeeded});

  factory ApiResponseBaseModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$ApiResponseBaseModelFromJson(json);
}

T _dataFromJson<T>(Map<String, dynamic> input) => input['data'] as T;

Map<String, dynamic> _dataToJson<T>(T input) => {'data': input};
```

When I try to decode json from api

```
final responseResult = ApiResponseBaseModel<List<Breed>>.fromJson(response);
```

throws type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'List' in type cast exception.

This is the json receiving from the api:

```
{
    "succeeded": true,
    "errors": null,
    "innerData": {
        "data": [
            {
                "id": "string",
                "title": "string",
                "animalType": 0
            },
            {
               "id": "string",
                "title": "string",
                "animalType": 0
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I tried cast < T > (input["data"]) but didn't work. Is there any solution ?

thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Your JSON structure has different types (strings, numbers, null and inner values). You trying to cast a response to a list of Breed entities but you should cast each data value in response to Breed and then create a list. You can visit to official [Flutter JSON and serialization docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json) page and find some examples about data conversion.

Comment: I also have Breed class with those properties inside data node and it also has fromJson method. When try to debug the app I can see the Map exactly same with breed list but could not cast it

Comment: You cannot cast to collection by this `input['data'] as T`. You should manually retrieve data from `input` and put it to a collection like `input['data'].map((item) => Bread.fromJson(data)).toList();`.